# How can I start iBeacon while my app is not running?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

How can I start iBeacon while my app is not running. 
I mean there must me some broadcast receiver which can be placed in my app's Manifest.

**Edit:**

As this question is misleading, let me rephrase it again:

I've created a project which detects the iBeacon 
1. In activity running state.
2. In service.

If I want be get notified whenever an iBeacon gets detected, when application is not running I've got one option that is through Service. But that will drain the battery. So is there any broadcast receiver which an notify my app as soon as any iBeacon is detected.

The Demo code which I've written for this is:
https://github.com/Vinayrraj/Android-iBeacon-Demo

Comment: iBeacon is a piece of decoupled external hardware, assuming that you mean [this iBeacon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBeacon). What are  you expecting to "start" "while [your] app is not running"?

Comment: If there is a way my app gets notified about the Beacon being detected, than I can start a service and perform the required task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply have to run a service in the background to do this.  Code has to run to detect iBeacons (e.g. Radius Networks' [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/)).    If you don't have a service running, then what is going to do the background detection?

Yes, anything running in the background will drain the battery, but it won't drain the battery much if it is sleeping most of the time.  Reducing the scan frequency can save battery life.  iOS7, for example, the OS only does a bluetooth scan once every few minutes when no foreground app is ranging for iBeacons.

So the solution to the battery problem is to reduce the frequency of the bluetooth scans in the service so they give you an acceptable trade-off between battery life and iBeacon detection speed.  If you are using my company's [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/), then. you can adjust the constant for this to your liking.

**EDIT:** My company has released a "Pro" version of the Android iBeacon Library with a built-in  ability to launch an app when one or more iBeacons are seen.  It also includes an automatic battery saver to slow down bluetooth scans whenever your app is in the background.  See code examples here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/pro/download.html

Comment: Thanks David, I was expecting an answer from you. Yes I'm using iBeacon Lib provided by your company. Thanks buddy !!

Answer (score -1):

In order to do something on Android, you have to create an Application. In order to make something work, something that you coded, you need to run your app. So it is not possible to do something like what you want. 
Sorry, mate.

Comment: Not particularly accurate or insightful.  Normally, an app can register in its manifest to be activated on certain conditions, however receipt of a BLE advertising packet in Apple's format is not a condition currently supported by the Android system.   So a background service within an app would need to scan for and interpret these, and then generate a condition (Intent).

Comment: Buddy I'hv a working application for that, wail, let me give you a link to GitHup repo where you can download the app. Its working completely fine. Detecting the Beacons when the app is in forground.

Comment: I think background service is not a good idea, as it will drain the battery. De we have any BroadcastReceiver for this ?

Comment: Wait a second: you were taking the in discussion the background service. That means the application is running. You asked that "while my app is not running" . A service that is running.. that means the app is running. Maybe I don't understand a lot of things, it is also possible that I'm not that good in reading/writing/understanding English language but a service is an Android application that is running, it is not in foreground, it is in background but is still running, as far as I know. Of course I might be wrong.........

Comment: Okay, lets understand it again, I want get notified whenevera an iBeacon is detected. I'm able to perform this when app is in foreground or through a Service when app is in background. But running a service continuesly drains cell's battery. So I want a Broadcast receiver, so that my app gets notified that a device is detected, than i can perform the required task, that way i can save a lot of cell's battery !! :)

Comment: Because beacon detection is not a built-in feature of the Android system, yes, you are going to have to wake up app-packaged code periodically or via *some other trigger*, and run your own code to cause a scan and interpret any results which might be iBeacon-style broadcasts.